# Add Worker Service project to abp.io solution

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

I have an abp.io solution to which I'd like to add worker service project (later to be used as windows service).

**How do I go about integrating worker service project with existing abp.io infrastructure?**

Since I'd like to use ABP's Domain project that gives me data access to DB in other functionalities.

Thank your for all your replies!

Comment: Did you check [this](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/5369)?

Comment: I haven't, but looking at it, feels a bit oudated given the current version of abp.io platform. I opened new [issue](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/5867) and also managed to do a working example. Just need to see if that is the way to go.